# How to combine TimeSeries of different dimensionality into TemporalData object?

Tags: time-series

I was wondering if it is possible to combine multiple `TimeSeries` data objects of values that have **different dimensionality** into one `TemporalData` object. Assume the following test scenario of two `TimeSeries` that are created from a list of integers (`s1`), a list of lists with three elements each (`s2`) and a list of time-values.

```
s1 = {{106, 126, 78}, {106, 123, 78}, {107, 120, 79}, {106, 118, 79}, {106, 117, 79}, {106, 117, 79}, {107, 116, 80}, {107, 116, 80}, {107, 117, 80}, {107, 120, 80}};
s2 = {157357, 157910, 156605, 156971, 156632, 155637, 154101, 153654, 152738, 151989};
t = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11};

{ts1,ts2} = Map[TimeSeries[#, {t}] &, {s1, s2}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Both `TimeSeries` are created and missing values are interpolated.

```
ts1[Range[11]]
```

> {157357, 157910, 156605, 156971, 156632, 155637, 154869, 154101, 153654, 152738, 151989}

```
ts2[Range[11]]
```

> {{106, 126, 78}, {106, 123, 78}, {107, 120, 79}, {106, 118, 79}, {106, 117, 79}, {106, 117, 79}, {213/2, 233/2, 159/2}, {107, 116, 80}, {107, 116, 80}, {107, 117, 80}, {107, 120, 80}}

However I cannot combine the two `TimeSeries` into one `TemporalData` object:

```
TemporalData[{ts1, ts2}]
```

> [image]

1. What is the problem?
2. Is there a workaround or do I have to stick to a list of `TimeSeries` in that case?
3. A side question: Is it possible to avoid extrapolation in `TimeSeries`?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Maybe `TemporalData[Join[TimeSeries/@Transpose[ts1["Values"]],{ts2}]]` for the second part of your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TemporalData` needs to assume equal dimensionality of series in order to distinguish between the case of a single multivariate series and multiple univariate series. There is no workaround to this limitation so you will need to stick to a list of `TimeSeries` objects.

Also, to avoid extrapolation you can always use a different setting for `ResamplingMethod`.  For example, setting it to `None` will cause it to return `Missing[]` anywhere the original data is not defined.

**EDIT**

I hadn't noticed that your data sets are each of the same length. I would echo @kguler's comment for a work-around.

```
TemporalData[Transpose[Transpose[s1]~Join~{s2}], {t}]
```

One possibility for avoiding extrapolation would be to wrap your `TimeSeries` or `TemporalData` in a function that specially handles edge behavior. For example:

```
noEx[ts_][t_?NumericQ] := 
 Piecewise[{{ts[t], ts["FirstTime"] <= t <= ts["LastTime"]}}, 
  Missing[]]

Plot[noEx[ts1][t], {t, 0, 12}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will try to do it with the workaround. Do you have an idea if it is possible to do interpolation of values in between but to avoid extrapolation?

Comment: Thanks for your update of the answer. That looks very promising!